# NPDA question about accepting condition

Tags: automata

Will an NPDA accept a string that reaches a final state but does not have all its input consumed yet?

Answer (score 1):

By “final state” I assume you mean “accepting state”. 
The answer is no, as the accepting state should have an empty string $\epsilon$ for it to be meaningful.

You can of course define a transition relation that consumes everything after it has reached an accepting state. It will act as a prefix detector.

Comment: Yes i meant accepting, sorry my bad. Thanks alot!